# How to assign HTML code to a variable in Windows shell script?

Tags: html, windows, shell

I can't believe I can't find this anywhere but I've searched and searched. I just want to assign some HTML code to a variable in a Windows shell script. E.g.:

```
set htmlstart=<html><head></head><body>
```

but when I do, I get "< was unexpected at this time."
If I wrap it in double quotes, then the variable contains those double quotes.
If I strip the first and last characters, I'm back to "< was unexpected at this time."

I've seen it recommended that I escape each "<" with "^<" and ">" with "^>" - but that doesn't work either - I still get "< was unexpected at this time."

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You didn't specify WIndows script engine: WSH, Powershell or batch-file. I've made the check - command-line worked: `set "htmlstart=(html)(head)(/head)(body)" & set "htmlstart=%htmlstart:(=^<%" & set "htmlstart=%htmlstart:)=^>%"` And `set "htmlstart=^<html^>^<head^>^</head^>^<body^>"`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Daemon-5! I never thought of using parentheses then replacing them with greater than/less than symbols. Very clever! It didn't work for me, though. After running that, I tried `echo {{ %htmlstart% }}` and it returned `< was unexpected at this time` The second method worked, though! BTW - I'm using the basic cmd engine.

Comment: Oops! Somehow I copied and pasted wrong, I guess. I retested the first method and it worked just fine.

Comment: `set "htmlstart=^<html^>^<head^>^</head^>^<body^>"`